# What specific instant in time in the MCU has been depicted the most times?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

With all the flashbacks and in-universe video and all the time-travel in *Avengers: Endgame*, it's not difficult to think of points in time that have been depicted multiple times, such as:

- Most of the times the heroes traveled to retrieve a Stone from the past
- The instant of the Unsnappening, which simultaneously occurs while the main heroes are in Upstate New York and in the high school gym in *Spider-Man: Far From Home*
- etc.

**But, is there any point in time, which we see three, four, maybe even five or more times?**

---

For the purpose of this question:

- The instant must be known to be the same instant (not just likely to be the same time).
- The instant can be still or video, part of the film or seen in-universe (diegetic or non-diegetic).   However, supporting materials (posters) and parts outside the film (e.g. the Marvel splash screen or parts of the credits) are out.   Post/mid-credits scenes are okay, of course.
- Different timelines are okay, if we know it's the same instant.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on the tagging (?)

Comment: is consideration given to the TV series? For example, Daredevil has newspaper clippings of the Battle of New York on display, etc...

Comment: @NKCampbell:   I guess it should.   It is MCU canon.

Comment: My money would be on the battle of New York, we see it in the Avengers, Endgame and Iron Man 3 off the top of my head, it might be shown in Ultron too.

Comment: Does Spider-Man watching a recording he made of the airport fight from *Civil War* in *Homecoming* count?

Comment: Does it need to be at least 3 times, or will 2 count? Does showing the aftermath of an event count, link in Spider Man Homecoming, where Toomes is shown as part of the clean-up crew? Finally, do TV shows count? Early seasons of Agents of SHIELD, for example, visited the aftermath of several main MCU events. (Thor: Dark World comes to mind).

Comment: "Dormammu, I've come to bargain."

Comment: @JDoe:   Good point!!   However, do we know technically, whether they are the same time, or merely it is a sequence of time that keeps resetting its state (mostly) and occurs while no time passes in the real world?   Does that question even make sense?

Comment: @ThePopMachine It's all a big ball of wibbly wobbly, timey wimey stuff anyway.

Comment: Are statues, posters on the walls, pictures on currency that depict a particular moment in time in scope?

Comment: @Koterpillar, tricky!  I'm not sure how to make the distinction, but I think we'd have to say that views of copies of objects (like statues or currency or posters) count as the same depiction.   Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: I just checked and (at least) American currency doesn't have any historical moments on it - that was my first thought. I think you closed the loophole well, though - it means the same video viewed multiple times won't count either.

Comment: @Koterpillar, [Not that it changes the answer](https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/File:US_%242_reverse.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

The Snap is shown *at least* 6 times.

- *Avengers: Infinity War* - Wakanda (various scenes, could count more than once)
- *Avengers: Infinity War* - Titan
- *Avengers: Infinity War* - New York
- *Ant-Man and the Wasp* - Los Angeles
- *Avengers: Endgame* - Clint's [safe] house
- *Spider-Man: Far From Home* - Midtown School of Science and Technology

---

We first see it in *Avengers: Infinity War* when Thanos snaps and we see how it affects various areas across the world: Wakanda, Titan and New York.

It is then shown in the post credits scene for *Ant-Man and the Wasp*.

We then see this again in the prologue to *Avengers: Endgame* and how it affected Clint and his family.

This is then shown again in *Spider-Man: Far From Home* in the in memorium video which shows the band and those in the stands being snapped away.

Comment: I suspect three is going to be beaten.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Wouldn’t surprise me but that depends on whether it counts as 3 or 5+ because of the different scenes and locations.

Comment: Scenes/locations counts if they are definitely simultaneous.

Comment: @ThePopMachine if I’m understanding you right this would count as at least 5 then I believe.

Comment: It would, if you can enumerate the instances, and we know they are not serial.

Comment: Not everybody was affected by the Snap simultaneously, so there's no definitive proof that these are the exact same moment in time. @ThePopMachine How much leeway are you allowing here? The post-Snap disappearances *probably* happen all within the same ~30 second period, but that's not the same instant in time.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I suppose like you said it depends on how the OP defines instant, however, each scene takes place over a period of time so it is quite likely they each show the same instant.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot:   Yes, we need to assume the Dustings are all overlapping.   Basically we need to infer whether the intent of the filmmakers is whether each of those shots is contemporaneous or serial.   Showing the same event/instant from multiple viewpoints is a specific device that is "unusual" in the sense that we don't experience the real world that way.   So usually, you can tell when the filmmaker is using this device.   In this case, it's the reasonable intepretation.

Comment: BTW, Carrot, I therefore agree that the shots in Wakanda could count multiple times.   We can't be sure, because in New York, it is 61 seconds between when the first car crashes and Fury dusts.   By my count, the maximum number in Wakanda would be six:   (Bucky, Wakanda warriors, Black Panther, Groot, Wanda, Sam).   The entire sequence (first dust to last dust) in Wakanda is 75 seconds.   So it's possible this is linear.

Comment: So given that, I change my answer and conclude we can't assume the shots in Wakanda are simultaneous.   Actually, I now think they **aren't**.   But at any rate, we can't be sure, so we must assume they aren't.

Comment: @ThePopMachine That's why I only say six but possibly more as we don't know if the shots in Wakanda are simultaneous or linear.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, yep.   I just looked at the video to see if there's any stronger evidence either way, and, as I said, the verdict is that it counts as definitively one.

Answer (score 7):

The deaths of Tony's parents in a car crash are seen four times, from different perspectives, in flashback and in video.

Comment: Could you edit in the times they are seen? And if you can find it a video clip of each would be great.